# How to access dynamically added controls using ID but ID could be changed in page source - php

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is a design question, might be a silly one but I need to know the answer.

I am developing a website where controls are added dynamically using jquery.

```
     var $link='<a id="bucket'+data[0].ID+'" class="Initial" href="#"></i></a>';  
     $($btnGroupdiv).append($link);
```

What I need to do is, I need to access this control and perform some actions which will be decided by what ID it has.

Now problem is that In browser page source, ID can be changed and could causes issues.

**Update:**

**This is how I am accessing it and making ajax call for ID.**

```
 $(".Initial").click(function(){

 var $pid=this.id.replace("bucket","");

      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://localhost/Voyager/Places/addBucketList',
            data:{'pid':$pid},
            success:function(){
              alert("success")                    

        });

            },
            failure:function(){
          alert("fail"); 
            }             
        });
```

So, here If ID is changed in browser, this will cause issue.

Is there anyway I can achieve this

Any solution to this??

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can detect the `id` of the `a` tag clicked on using the `class` name, and then depending on what `id` you get, you can perform the action required.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala thats what I am doing, but still ID is visible in source and could be changed which will cause issue

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this: *Now problem is that In browser page source, ID can be changed and could causes issues.* - who is going to change it?  If they are going to change it then what will the benefit be for them doing so?  If it is critical it should not be changed, then you should also do some server side validation

Comment: @Pete I mean to say this-> For ex: In chrome, Right click on any control-> Inspect-> there you have all attributes of control and it could be changed.

Comment: Please show us the code that is accessing this control by ID and causing issue.

Comment: @DKR everything has that risk, if it is going to be posting some critical data or you are using it as some sort of form submission, then you should be doing server side validation on it as well as your js validation - in case anyone turns their js off or tries to circumvent it by doing what you say.  If you are just appending it to the page then I don't see why you would be bothered if someone changed the id.  If they are going to mess with the source and break the site, then who cares if it doesn't do any actual damage?

Comment: @NawedKhan I have updated code in question

Comment: @Pete using ID, I am making changes in database where this ID is primary key, If someone changes the ID to something which matches in database, it will make change to a different row, this will be a disaster.

Comment: In which case you should think of a different way to do this - eg validate the user against the that id and make sure they have permission to update the record or check that the value posted matches the original item - for example you can post it with an array index and then match it up against the value in the original array before doing any update#

Comment: @Pete That will cause a huge performance issue, I might have hundreds of such controls on page, how do I match each control everytime it is clicked. There must be simpler solution.

Comment: Well good luck finding it, basically you are going to need to validate somehow, otherwise run the risk of letting the wrong people update the wrong records.  And I don't see it as a massive performance hit - not everyone will have access to every id - if they do then you need to have a look at your data architecture and start from the beginning and fix that first

Comment: what are you trying to do is in not in proper way then, that what I feel.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Tell me the proper way buddy

Comment: not able to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have 100 buttons on a page, On click of any control I need to add data in database for row for which primary key is id of that control. You have any simpler solution?

Comment: `need to add data in database` how you get it or what data along with PK?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala You arent getting me. I need to add xyz doesnt matter.. What matters is I want to add it to that specific row which primary key matches with id of that control.

Comment: so you already have the primary key with you on click of the class which is the `id` of the class clicked. What is the issue?

Comment: Please read question properly.

Comment: you have 2 options. Option 1 is to change the IDs from a number to a GUID or a long string that is unique and hard to guess. Option 2 is server side validation. It is NOT a performance issue. Only one row is saved on a click. Before putting in database check if the currently logged-in user has permission to update this ID or not. This is standard practice.

Comment: @NawedKhan All user have permission to do that, but if a malicious user change its ID, and clicking on button will update data for different user.